# mysql_query ("UPDATE... not updating

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me why its not updating the mysql query , the javascript its executing , all working but its just not updating into the table accounts and row "positive"

The row value should be '1'

Can anyone fix it THanks

```html
<script>
 function positive(accid)
 {
  top.document.location.href = "myaccounts.php?job=positive&positive="+accid;
 }
</script>    
<?php
if(isset($_GET["job"]) && $_GET["job"] == "positive" && !empty($_GET["positive"]))

 {
                $account_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["account_id"]);
                mysql_query("UPDATE `accounts` SET `positive`= '1' WHERE account_id = '$account_id'");


 }
?>

<td class="formstyle"><div align="center" style="padding:5px;">
<img src="" width="35" height="35" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="if(confirm(\'Confirm Positive Feedback ?\')) positive(\''.$row["account_id"].'\');" /></div>
</td>
```

Comment: In your last question you were told to add error checking. Did you try doing the same thing here?

Comment: No im trying now to update an existing data into the rows but the problem its here 
$account_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["account_id"]);
its not getting the account_id when i try it manually the ID it works , do u have any idea ?

Comment: Do you see the account ID in the `onclick` when you look at the HTML source?

Comment: Have you done the necessary debugging to be 100% sure that your code enters the `if` statement and actually runs your UPDATE statement ?  Have you verified that the `$account_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["account_id"]);`  gives you the exact account_id you think it does ?

Comment: Yes i see the account_id in on click

Comment: @nos yes in on click i can see the account_id but when i execute the code  $account_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["account_id"]);
Here its the problem in my TABLE i can i see the account_id , i dont know how to fix it any idea... please

Comment: @JoeFixer From what you are telling me, you have not verified what I suggested you should verify. You should add some code inside your `if` statement that writes something to your html page. Otherwise, how do you know that `isset($_GET["job"]) && $_GET["job"] == "positive" && !empty($_GET["positive"])` are all true, and that your code actually enters the body of your `if` statement ?

Comment: I have copied the code from an website , its used with an javascript to execute can u complet it please ?

Answer (score -1):

Your SQL syntax is wrong, the $account_id should be concatenated.

Comment: He's using backticks, that's MySQL's way of quoting database and column names.

Comment: Yes i see the account_id in on click